# Set Airflow Env Vars at Runtime

Tags: airflow

If I set env vars corresponding to airflow config settings after executing the `airflow` binary and at the same time DAG definitions are being loaded into memory, will this have the same effect as having set these same env vars at the OS level prior to having executed the binary?

Comment: How are you setting the environment variables?

Comment: @joeb One way to do something like this would be to add a config.py file to you DAGs directory that, when loaded into memory, uses the `sys` package to set environment variables for the running process.

Comment: Then no, that isn't the same thing as having them set at the operating system.

Comment: yep, that's why I asked the question :)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find any documentation on whether this would work as intended and figured that if I had to read through the source to figure this out then it's probably not a good idea to be doing it in the first place.

Instead of setting environment variables at runtime I've created two `airflow.cfg` files: `airflow.prod.cfg` and `airflow.dev.cfg`. I then created a shell script `start.sh` that `cp`s the appropriate `.cfg` file to `airflow.cfg` prior to executing the `airflow` binary.

I don't love having to use the shell script to boot things up but I'd prefer that to chancing any kind of spooky action as a result of setting env vars at runtime.