# Where to store credentials for AWS EMR Apache Spark application submitted from Airflow task

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, airflow

I'm working on Apache Spark application which I submit to AWS EMR cluster from Airflow task.

In Spark application logic I need to read files from AWS S3 and information from AWS RDS. For example, in order to connect to AWS RDS on PostgreSQL from Spark application, I need to provide the username/password for the database.

Right now I'm looking for the best and secure way in order to keep these credentials in the safe place and provide them as parameters to my Spark application. Please suggest where to store these credentials in order to keep the system secured - as env vars, somewhere in Airflow or where?

Comment: Look at AWS blogs for secure ways to do it, here is one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-credentialsprovider.html

Answer (score 1):

In Airflow you can create Variables to store this information. Variables can be listed, created, updated and deleted from the UI (Admin -> Variables). You can then access them from your code as follows:

```
from airflow.models import Variable
foo = Variable.get("foo")
```

Answer (score 1):

`Airflow` has got us covered beautifully on *credentials-management* front by offering [`Connection` *`SQLAlchemy` model*](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L603) that can be [accessed from WebUI](https://airflow.apache.org/howto/manage-connections.html) (where *passwords still remain hidden*)

- You can [control the `salt`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L136) that `Airflow` uses to encrypt passwords while storing `Connection`-details in it's backend meta-db.
- It also provides you `extra` param for storing unstructured / client-specific stuff [such as `{"use_beeline": true}` *config*](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L63) for `Hiveserver2`
- In addition to WebUI, you can also edit `Connection`s [via `CLI`](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#connections) (which is true for pretty much every feature of `Airflow`)
- Finally if your use-case involves [**dynamically creating / deleting a `Connection`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53740885/3679900), that is also possible by exploiting the underlying `SQLAlchemy` `Session`. You can see implementation details from [`cli.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/bin/cli.py#L1116)

*Note that `Airflow` treats all `Connection`s equal irrespective of [their `type`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L624) (type is just a hint for the end-user). `Airflow` distinguishes them on the [basis of `conn_id`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L613) only*